# Language Popup on page load

Tags: html, popup

Does anyone know how to do like a language popup on page load? We are doing a site for a company and we are kinda new to html.

Something just like this:

**Language Popup**

[image]

Comment: i dont have a code, i want to make one for my site. The image is from another site

Comment: What language? What libraries? What have you tried already? ......... StackOverflow is not a service to write applications from scratch.

Comment: chill dude, im using html and css, can use js too i guess. Havent tried yet, because im fixing something, and want to get some work done

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
 $(".open").click(function () {
        $(".popup").fadeIn(500);
        $(".cover").fadeTo(500, 0.5);
    });

    $(".close").click(function () {
        $(".popup").fadeOut(500);
        $(".cover").fadeOut(500);
    });
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/TwLMD/76/)